# Should I use Redis to cache the response of queries?

Tags: caching, redis, parse-server

I have a social app on a `Parse Server` (Ubuntu) and I need to cache server-side the users' content, like their main feed and chat, in order to speed things up. Is Redis suitable for that kind of caching? If not, what would you recommend?

Also, I was thinking a way to minimize my db reads and I came up with an idea of an up-to-date cache, where I'll have `triggers` on new post saves and there, I'll be refreshing my cache. Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis can deifnitely be used to cache stuff. Twitter uses (or at least used to) Redis to cache the timeline. [This blog post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/9/8/how-twitter-uses-redis-to-scale-105tb-ram-39mm-qps-10000-ins.html) can give you more insight as to how they use it. Lot of good snippets of information for why Redis was chosen.